# Magento - How do I add a frontend date picker that returns DD/MM/YY instead of MM/DD/YY?

Tags: magento

In my form I have:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Date') ?>: 
<input type="text" name="cal_date" id="cal_date" value="" /> 
<img title="Select date" id="cal_date_trig" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN) . 'adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif'; ?>"  class="v-middle"/>
```

This shows the calendar.

In the header I have:

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
</reference>
```

This loads the js and css.

In the layout xml I have:

```
<block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
```

This adds the calendar picker to the page when I include this in my template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('html_calendar') ?>
```

I get no errors and the date picker works.

I have set the date format in the backend to dd/mm/yy with en_GB locale. However I am still getting US date formats. How can I get UK date formats?

Comment: When I had the same question, this page helped me, but I had to combine elements from several of the answers here.

Answer (score 7):

You can place calendar on the form like this:

```
<input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to" value="" /> 
<input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'date_from',
    ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
    button : 'date_from_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    singleClick : true
});

Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'date_to',
    ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
    button : 'date_to_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    singleClick : true
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: You also have to had the button trigger (date_from_trig or date_to_trig in your example), just after the input : 

`<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif') ?>" class="v-middle" id="date_from_trig" />`

Answer (score 3):

You have to add:

```
 <block type="core/html_calendar" name="head.calendar" as="calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
```

in head refernce to get this working in 1.7

Answer (score 2):

Change the format in the javascript as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Calendar.setup({
  inputField : 'date_from',
  ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
  button : 'date_from_trig',
  align : 'Bl',
  singleClick : true
  });
</script>
```

change the ifFormat to '%e%m%y' which will be like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Calendar.setup({
  inputField : 'date_from',
  ifFormat : '%e%m%y',
  button : 'date_from_trig',
  align : 'Bl',
  singleClick : true     
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

changing the ifFormat to '%e%m%y' changes the input type to d/m/y (which is what i required) but when i view the account information the date is changed to 1970/01/01. should i make changes is the database to store the date as d/m/y??