# How can call calendar.phtml in footer.phtml file

Tags: magento, calendar

How can I call the built in calendar block in my footer.phtml file ?

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/calendar.phtml.
```

how can I call that file as block in my footer.phtml ? (ie:for newsletter we write

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter‌​/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

in footer.phtml)

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
</reference>
```

In your calendar.phtml

```
<input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
Calendar.setup({
    inputField : 'date_from',
    ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
    button : 'date_from_trig',
    align : 'Bl',
    singleClick : true
});
</script>
```

in footer.phtml

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'core/template',
    'calendar_block',
    array('template' => 'path/to/calendar.phtml')
)->toHtml();
```

See [Magento - How do I add a frontend date picker that returns DD/MM/YY instead of MM/DD/YY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335456/magento-how-do-i-add-a-frontend-date-picker-that-returns-dd-mm-yy-instead-of-m)

Comment: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/calendar.phtml. how can I call that file as block in my footer.phtml ? (ie:for newsletter we write <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?> in footer.phtml)

Comment: I put the xml code in page.xml, input box and javascript code in calendar.phtml and '<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template','calendar_block',array('template' =>'page/js/calendar.phtml'))->toHtml(); ?>' this one in footer.xml. but there a horizontal line came only. nothing else. what was the wrong ?

Comment: footer.xml or footer.phtml? where did you put `<reference name="head">`

Comment: and added <reference name="head"> in page.xml